# How to make my HP LaserJet 1000 printer work with Ubuntu live CD and save the settings?

Tags: 12.04, printing, live-cd

I just want my LaserJet 1000 printer to work with Ubuntu live CD and save the settings.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I thought Ubuntu already had hplip to work with LaserJet 1000 little box. But when I connect the printer it causes an error and won't download the required plugin for my printer.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that it required some serious hassle to get it working...
Anyways, try this link: [HP Laserjet 1000 series driver](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=45675&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=45674&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2020) and download the driver and get it installed. If i remember correctly, that was the one you had to install, Ubuntu did not get you a open-source one on installation.

Comment: That link goes straight to hplip? I thought ubuntu 12.04 already has hplip ?.. Can you explain further why I need to re download it if its already installed in Bantu 12.04 isn't it already installed by default in the ubuntu 12.04 live cd?

Comment: I tried download that link it goes to hplip and hplip comes back with error 500 which I'm told is a server problem by Shauna here on this forum